# Is there a package to prepare MPD for video streaming from multiple identical HTTP sources for MPEG-DASH?

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, html5-video, cdn, mpeg-dash

I would like to program something that can play using MPEG-DASH for use in a web video player such as [shaka-player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player). I've been looking at using node.js and a setup similar to [D-DASH](http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=958).

So say I have bugsbunny.mp4 mirrored on 10 different servers, I would like to have a script that acts in a pseudo-torrenty way and creates an MPD from those .mp4's based on whichever server is the fastest to respond *for each chunk/segment* of the video.

(This is kind of like a CDN acts but rather than optimize based on the client's location the selection of CDN servers to use to transfer data, I would like to optimize the streaming for each chunk in the MPD by checking and selecting the best URL)

other requirments:
- cannot pre-process or encode the .mp4 to create pre-carved segments (I need to use these mp4's at run-time as is)
- would like to create the manifest MPD on the client machine, not on the server

I'm note sure the design approach to take for this.  I've heard of P2P projects like Peer5 but I don't know if that's the way I want to go.  I want to be able to consider multiple HTTP sources for video files and select the URL source for segments on the fly. If anyone could recommend general approaches to achieve this, that would be great.

Comment: I think MPEG-DASH actually has that feature already built in. From what I recall you can just specify 10 Base URLs for each of your servers and let it figure out itself. If you're thinking of optimizing the Base URLs given in the MPD based on the client situation, that could actually be tough.

Comment: I was hoping though in addition to optimize the retrieval of each segments / chunks. This would be difficult but make things potentially faster. Although thanks that's good to know about the 10 base URLs.

Comment: Something similar is discussed here:https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/shaka-player-users/sY2pLQrQdvw/g6tKOmsoCgAJ